# How to get any first heading tags in post and display the result?

Tags: php, html, regex, wordpress

I want to change `the_title()` to heading tag that i placed/wrote in posts, i already create list loop post with table code and got stuck in here... Any help?

Format Title: `<h3 style="text-align: center;">Title Here</h3>`

```
<div class="chapter_release">
<table><tr>
    <th>Chapter</th> 
</tr>
<?php
// Posts are found
if ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
        $posts->the_post();
        global $post;
?>
<tr><td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td></tr>
<?php
    }
}
?></table></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that heading is h2:

```
<div class="chapter_release">
<table><tr>
    <th>Chapter</th> 
</tr>
<?php
// Posts are found
if ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
        $posts->the_post();
        global $post;
        if( preg_match( "'<h2>(.*?)</h2>'si", get_the_content(), $match ) == 1 ) {
            $new_title = $match[1];
        } else {
            $new_title = get_the_title();
        }
?>
<tr><td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $new_title; ?></a></td></tr>
<?php
    }
}
?></table></div>
```

Comment: I usually use H3 and align center.

Comment: I fixed by myself, Thank you. I will still approve your answer because i only change preg_match.